# The most reliable way to deliver data to external storages

Tags: design, architecture, files

I have a question about best-practices in terms of reliability.

There is some data residing in RAM of some process and the data needs to be delivered in a bunch of external storage providing the least possibility for data loss. **The data are not required to be read again by the process.**

I currently think that the way to go is to dump the data on a local drive and then deliver the data into the storages with some external tool. I see the following benefit:

1. Writing to a single drive is much less likely to fail then say 1 of 10 external storages the data needs to be delivered to
2. Abstracting away the storage type the data are delivered into.
3. Simplifying the logic of the process which generates the data.

I see the following drawbacks:

1. Local disk usually have much less capacity then external storages

**So I assume in case the data are not required to be read again it is a good practice to dump it on a local drive first and then deliver with some external tool. Is it?**

Comment: Depends on how you define "Best". Generally writing to a single location is far simpler from an app perspective, especially given how reliable, configurable, and open to recovery most file management and transfer software is. As for local vs network, I've production apps using both strategies.

Comment: Having to develop two applications takes more development effort than developing one, which means more cost in both development and maintenance. So when you say "best", are you factoring in the cost of development/maintenance, or are you purely asking for the most reliable - no matter the cost/effort?

Comment: What kind of reliability are you looking for? Reliable writes? Reliable reads? Can you define what you mean by "reliability?"